# center div horizontally in it's parent when parent is smaller that child

Tags: html, css

Basically the title. I would like to center a child in it's parent, but the child is bigger than the parent. How can I do that?

```css
#cont {
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}

#main {
  width: 130%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically with your styling you can do this. If this is what you mean

```css
#cont{
  width:30%;
  padding-top:30%;
  background-color:red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

}

#main{
  width:130%;
  padding-top:30%;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  top:35%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
<div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`position: absolute;` and `left:0;right:0;` with `margin: auto;`
you can suit your rules to implement this in your case

```css
.outer
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
.inner
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example has a very different css than that of OP's

Comment: @Tesseract my answer was aiming to show a possible way of achieving what he wants. its not based on his code

Comment: It would be very useful if you can produce an answer based on what OP provided. Giving an answer not same as the OP's, might give the OP another thinking on how to convert your answer to his needs, especially since he provided a code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? This is centered horizontally only using `transform: translate` and `position:absolute`

```css
#cont {
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  width: 130%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why downvoting this answer?

Comment: @mjanisz1 Someone did down vote. Sadly he/she didn't leave an explanation

Answer (score 0):

If your div is 30% larger than it's parrent you can just give it a margin-left of -15%

```css
#cont{
  width:30%;
  padding-top:30%;
  background-color:red;
  margin:auto;
}

#main{
  width:130%;
  padding-top:30%;
  background-color:blue;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left: -15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
<div id="main"></div>
</div>
```